# Error initializing Tor in pythonanywhere - Stuck at 5%

Tags: linux, ubuntu, browser, tor, pythonanywhere

I´m making a project in [pythonanywhere](https://pythonanywhere.com) , I have installed Tor, but when I run it I´m getting this message:

```
Sep 13 15:04:29.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 5% (conn): Connecting to a relay. (Connection refused; CONNECTREFUSED; count 10; recommendation warn; host 24E2F139121D4394C54B5BCC368B3B411857C413 at
 204.13.164.118:443)
Sep 13 15:04:29.000 [warn] 9 connections have failed:
Sep 13 15:04:29.000 [warn]  9 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object)
Sep 13 15:04:36.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 5% (conn): Connecting to a relay. (Connection refused; CONNECTREFUSED; count 11; recommendation warn; host D8B7A3A6542AA54D0946B9DC0257C53B6C376679 at
 85.10.201.47:9001)
Sep 13 15:04:36.000 [warn] 10 connections have failed:
Sep 13 15:04:36.000 [warn]  10 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object)
Sep 13 15:04:37.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 5% (conn): Connecting to a relay. (Connection refused; CONNECTREFUSED; count 12; recommendation warn; host A0F06C2FADF88D3A39AA3072B406F09D7095AC9E at
 46.165.230.5:443) ...
```

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would not work on free PythonAnywhere accounts as free accounts can only connect to the outer world using the HTTP protocol. Also, free accounts are limited to the whitelist. See https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/